# APL skill without lambda functions

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating Alexa echo show skill, I have created one sample Alexa skill without lambda function that hits myserver api and I return response in Alexa accepted format like below:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "My output speech"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "Simple",
      "title": "hELLO",
      "content": "Meetings"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": "Can I help you with anything else?"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  }
}
```

Till now my skill working fine, But now I want to show a template over the echo show that is possible with APL(Alexa Programming Language).

I am not getting APL examples without lambda function, I have tried to add some APL response json from the example that i got and put into above response json that is not working.

I am confused with APL, Should i just need to add some attribute only in the above response or need to use sdk at my server that is running with PHP whose sdk i did not find at the portal.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send an APL document, you have to send a [directive](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test/amzn1.ask.skill.0b32b115-1293-4c66-926d-cd5c7854206a/development/en_US/) to the JSON

```
{
  "body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": "<speak>Hello world, change me</speak>"
      },
      "directives": [
        {
          "type": "Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument",
          "token": "TemplateTypescript",
          "document": {
            "type": "APL",
            "version": "1.7",
            "license": "Copyright 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.\nSPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-.amazon.com.-AmznSL-1.0\nLicensed under the Amazon Software License  http://aws.amazon.com/asl/",
            "theme": "dark",
            "import": [
              {
                "name": "alexa-layouts",
                "version": "1.4.0"
              }
            ],
            "resources": [
              {
                "description": "Default dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline.",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "100%",
                  "secondaryTextMaxWidth": "100%",
                  "secondaryTextTopPadding": "@spacingXSmall",
                  "contentPaddingLeft": "@marginHorizontal"
                },
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 2
                },
                "strings": {
                  "textComponentAlign": "center"
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions for the AlexaHeadline - hubLandscapeLarge.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @hubLandscapeLarge}",
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions for the AlexaHeadline - hubRound.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfileCategory == @hubRound}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "secondaryTextTopPadding": "@spacing3XSmall"
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions for the AlexaHeadline - tvLandscapeOverlay/tvLandscapeXLarge.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @tvLandscapeXLarge || @viewportProfile == @tvLandscapeOverlay}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "560dp",
                  "secondaryTextMaxWidth": "560dp",
                  "secondaryTextTopPadding": "@spacing3XSmall"
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions for the AlexaHeadline - tvLandscapeXLarge.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @tvLandscapeXLarge}",
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - tvPortraitOverlay.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @tvPortraitOverlay}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "220dp",
                  "secondaryTextMaxWidth": "220dp",
                  "contentPaddingLeft": "@spacing2XLarge"
                },
                "strings": {
                  "textComponentAlign": "left"
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - mobileSmall portrait.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @mobileSmall && @viewportOrientation == @viewportOrientationPortrait}",
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - mobileMedium.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @mobileMedium}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "758dp"
                },
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - mobileLarge.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @mobileLarge}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "1025dp"
                },
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - hubPortraitMedium.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @hubPortraitMedium}",
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "Dimensions, numbers and strings for the AlexaHeadline - hubLandscapeXLarge.",
                "when": "${@viewportProfile == @hubLandscapeXLarge}",
                "dimensions": {
                  "primaryTextMaxWidth": "1440dp"
                },
                "numbers": {
                  "headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines": 4
                }
              }
            ],
            "styles": {
              "primaryTextLight": {
                "extends": "textStyleDisplay4",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "color": "@colorTextReversed"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "secondaryTextLight": {
                "extends": "textStyleCallout",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "color": "@colorTextReversed"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "layouts": {
              "AlexaHeadline": {
                "parameters": [
                  {
                    "name": "theme",
                    "description": "Colors will be switched depending on the specified theme (light/dark). Default to dark theme",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "dark"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "primaryText",
                    "description": "Primary message",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "secondaryText",
                    "description": "secondary message",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerAttributionOpacity",
                    "type": "number",
                    "default": "${@viewportProfileCategory == @hubRound ? 1 : @opacitySecondary}"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerTitle",
                    "description": "Primary text to render in header.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerSubtitle",
                    "description": "Secondary text to render in header.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerAttributionText",
                    "description": "Attribution text to render in header. Only shown when no headerAttributionImage is provided, and when headerAttributionPrimacy is true, or on a device that shows Title/Subtitle and Attribution.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerAttributionImage",
                    "description": "URL for attribution image source. Only shown when headerAttributionPrimacy is true, or on a device that shows Title/Subtitle and Attribution.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerAttributionPrimacy",
                    "description": "On devices that can only display one element due to screen size, Attribution is prioritized. Setting False displays Title/Subtitle.  Defaults to true.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": true
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerDivider",
                    "description": "Toggle to display the divider that appears at the bottom of header to help separate it from the content below. Default to false",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerBackButton",
                    "description": "Toggle to display back button in header. Defaults to false.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerBackButtonAccessibilityLabel",
                    "description": "An accessibility label to describe the back button to customers who use a screen reader.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerBackButtonCommand",
                    "description": "Command that is issued when back button is pressed.",
                    "type": "any",
                    "default": {
                      "type": "SendEvent",
                      "arguments": ["goBack"]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "headerBackgroundColor",
                    "description": "Optional color value to use as background color for Header. Defaults to transparent.",
                    "type": "color",
                    "default": "transparent"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundColor",
                    "description": "Color value to use as background color for layout.",
                    "type": "color"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundImageSource",
                    "description": "URL for background image source.",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundVideoSource",
                    "description": "URL for background video source.",
                    "type": "any"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundScale",
                    "description": "Image/video scale to apply to background image/video. Defaults to best-fill.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "best-fill"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundAlign",
                    "description": "Image/video alignment to apply to background image/video. Defaults to center.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "align": "center"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundBlur",
                    "description": "Toggle to apply background blur. Defaults to false.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundColorOverlay",
                    "description": "Toggle to apply overlay scrim to background image/video. Defaults to false.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundOverlayGradient",
                    "description": "Toggle to apply gradient to background image/video. Defaults to false.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundVideoAutoPlay",
                    "description": "Toggle to autoplay background video(s). Defaults to false.",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "backgroundVideoAudioTrack",
                    "description": "Audio track to play on. Defaults to foreground. EM can select foreground | background | none.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "foreground"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "footerHintText",
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hint text to display in Footer."
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "entities",
                    "description": "Array of entity data bind to this layout",
                    "type": "any"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "layoutDirection",
                    "description": "The layoutDirection of AlexaHeadline. It can be LTR or RTL. By default, it uses environment layoutDirection.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "${environment.layoutDirection}"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "lang",
                    "description": "The lang property of AlexaHeadline. Set the lang property to a BCP-47 string (e.g., en-US). By default, it uses environment lang.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "${environment.lang}"
                  }
                ],
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "layoutDirection": "${layoutDirection}",
                    "height": "100vh",
                    "entities": "${entities}",
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "type": "AlexaBackground",
                        "backgroundColor": "${backgroundColor}",
                        "backgroundImageSource": "${backgroundImageSource}",
                        "backgroundVideoSource": "${backgroundVideoSource}",
                        "backgroundScale": "${backgroundScale}",
                        "backgroundAlign": "${backgroundAlign}",
                        "backgroundBlur": "${backgroundBlur}",
                        "colorOverlay": "${backgroundColorOverlay}",
                        "overlayGradient": "${backgroundOverlayGradient}",
                        "videoAutoPlay": "${backgroundVideoAutoPlay}",
                        "videoAudioTrack": "${backgroundVideoAudioTrack}"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "height": "100vh",
                        "width": "100vw",
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "items": [
                          {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "grow": 1,
                            "justifyContent": "center",
                            "paddingLeft": "@contentPaddingLeft",
                            "paddingRight": "@marginHorizontal",
                            "alignItems": "center",
                            "items": [
                              {
                                "when": "${primaryText && primaryText != ''}",
                                "type": "Text",
                                "style": "${theme == 'light' ? 'primaryTextLight' : 'textStyleDisplay4'}",
                                "text": "${primaryText}",
                                "opacity": 1,
                                "textAlign": "@textComponentAlign",
                                "maxWidth": "@primaryTextMaxWidth",
                                "maxLines": "@headlinePrimaryTextMaxLines"
                              },
                              {
                                "when": "${secondaryText && secondaryText != ''}",
                                "type": "Text",
                                "style": "${theme == 'light' ? 'secondaryTextLight' : 'textStyleCallout'}",
                                "text": "${secondaryText}",
                                "maxLines": 1,
                                "opacity": "@opacitySecondary",
                                "textAlign": "@textComponentAlign",
                                "maxWidth": "@secondaryTextMaxWidth",
                                "paddingTop": "@secondaryTextTopPadding"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "AlexaHeader",
                            "theme": "${theme}",
                            "headerTitle": "${headerTitle}",
                            "layoutDirection": "${layoutDirection}",
                            "headerSubtitle": "${@viewportProfile != @tvLandscapeOverlay ? headerSubtitle : ''}",
                            "headerAttributionText": "${headerAttributionText}",
                            "headerAttributionImage": "${headerAttributionImage}",
                            "headerAttributionPrimacy": "${headerAttributionPrimacy}",
                            "headerDivider": "${headerDivider}",
                            "headerBackButton": "${headerBackButton}",
                            "headerBackButtonAccessibilityLabel": "${headerBackButtonAccessibilityLabel}",
                            "headerBackButtonCommand": "${headerBackButtonCommand}",
                            "headerBackgroundColor": "${headerBackgroundColor}",
                            "headerAttributionOpacity": "${headerAttributionOpacity}",
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "width": "100%",
                            "top": "0"
                          },
                          {
                            "when": "${@viewportProfileCategory != @hubRound && @viewportProfile != @tvLandscapeOverlay && footerHintText}",
                            "type": "AlexaFooter",
                            "hintText": "${footerHintText}",
                            "theme": "${theme}",
                            "lang": "${lang}",
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "width": "100%",
                            "bottom": "0"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "mainTemplate": {
              "parameters": ["payload"],
              "item": [
                {
                  "type": "AlexaHeadline",
                  "id": "PlantHeadline",
                  "primaryText": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.textContent.primaryText.text}",
                  "headerBackButton": false,
                  "headerAttributionImage": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.logoUrl}",
                  "headerAttributionPrimacy": true,
                  "footerHintText": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.hintText}",
                  "backgroundImageSource": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.backgroundImage.sources[0].url}",
                  "backgroundColorOverlay": false,
                  "speech": "${payload.headlineTemplateData.properties.welcomeSpeech}",
                  "theme": "light"
                }
              ]
            },
            "onMount": [
              {
                "type": "SpeakItem",
                "componentId": "PlantHeadline"
              }
            ]
          },
          "datasources": {
            "headlineTemplateData": {
              "type": "object",
              "objectId": "headlineSample",
              "properties": {
                "backgroundImage": {
                  "sources": [
                    {
                      "url": "https://d2o906d8ln7ui1.cloudfront.net/images/templates_v3/headline/HeadlineBackground_Light.png",
                      "size": "large"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "textContent": {
                  "primaryText": {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "text": "Welcome to Template Typescript"
                  }
                },
                "logoUrl": "",
                "hintText": ""
              }
            }
          },
          "timeoutType": "SHORT"
        }
      ],
      "reprompt": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "type": "SSML",
          "ssml": "<speak>Hello world, change me</speak>"
        }
      },
      "shouldEndSession": false,
      "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "userAgent": "ask-node/2.11.0 Node/v12.22.4"
  }
}
```

You can use https://apl.ninja/ or [within the developer console](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/multimodal) to help you get started quickly.

Comment: above response json showing issue

Comment: thanks it worked for me with some different response json